# Unable to resolve localhost after having installed Rancher desktop

Tags: google-chrome, locale

I recently installed Rancher desktop, with dockerd (moby) container runtime.

Now, with Chrome, I cannot reach services exposed on localhost.

The same services are reachable at 127.0.0.1.

In the hosts file, I notice that 127.0.0.1 is mapped to `host.docker.internal` (with a comment indicating that the line was added by Rancher desktop).

How can the issue be fixed? Is it safe to edit the  hosts file, adding an entry to map 127.0.0.1 (also) to localhost? Or maybe there is some setting to be applied to Rancher desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found (on a Windows machine) that if I go into File... Preferences... Network... WSL and click the "Enable networking tunnel" box, it solved my problem.  Previously, I could not hit "localhost", but "127.0.0.1" did work.  But after I ticked this box, then addresses like "http://localhost:90" did work.  Hope that helps someone.

[image]